# On a remark in Foundations of mechanics, 2nd Edition, by Abraham and Marsden

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a $2$-form $\omega$ on a manifold $M$, let us denote by $N$ the kernel of $\omega$, i.e. $N:=\{u\in TM : \omega(u,\cdot)=0\}$.  Their Proposition 5.1.2 shows that if $\omega$ has constant rank (and is closed) then $N$ is a tangent distribution on $M$ (and completely integrable).

In the following remark they say that the reader can easily prove the converse of the previous conclusion.  While I understand that $N$ is a tangent distribution if and only if $\omega$ has constant rank. Instead I think that, for $\omega$ of constant rank, $N$ can be completely integrable even if $\omega$ is not closed, (e.g. $\omega=e^z dx\wedge dy$).

> My first question is: Do I have misunderstood something, or not?

Given a $\omega\in\mathcal{A}^p(M)$ whose rank is constant, let us define its kernel $N$ as above.  Evidently $N$ is a tangent distribution on $M$, and I find it is completely integrable at least when there exists a $1$-form $\phi$ such that $d\omega=\phi\wedge\omega$.

> My second question is : what is a necessary and sufficient condition for the complete integrability of  $N$?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: your counter example semms convincing.

Comment: @Olivier Bégassat: I have added a second issue related to the same remark in Abraham and Marsden. Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: Also posted to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73914/on-a-remark-in-foundations-of-mechanics-2nd-edition-by-abraham-and-marsden